# How do I change Windows 7 to boot normally instead of in safe-mode?

Tags: windows-7, boot, safe-mode

I was not able to boot in safe mode on my Windows 7 PC, so I went into boot manager and checked off *boot into safe mode* to see if that would fix the issue. Unfortunately it did not, and now my PC seems only to be able to keep trying to boot into safe-mode. Is there a way to set it back to regular normal boot from outside of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

When the computer is booting up, you should be able to press <kbd>F8</kbd> (repetitively) while it is booting as soon as you reach POST . It will eventually boot to a menu allowing you to boot into normal mode, safe mode, or safe mode with networking.

I think you can still get into msconifg while in safe mode, then un-check the box for "Safe boot". After that, click "Apply" and you should be good to go.

Comment: The issue is that it can't boot into safemode. It fails, but use last settings option still has it boot to safemode, not a normal boot.

Comment: Does it give an error when it fails? Also, did you try repeatedly pressing F8 while it was booting?

Comment: Looks like disabling RAID and setting it to IDE allowed it to boot into safemode will use your tip to turn it off.